# Way to geometry of numbers

Tags: geometry

I would like to know what are the prerequisites to learning geometry of numbers .
I want to read and understand the work that Minkowski was involved in when he was 17 years old . I have the followin lecture notes .These are the works of H.Smith and Minkowski . It starts up with Hermite and Smith natural forms and move on to something called  Mahler's compactness theorem  and then to Gauss's circle problem and so on .
[http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/geometryofnumbers.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/geometryofnumbers.pdf)

can anyone explain to me what are the pre-requisites for understanding these lecture series ?

Comment: What background do you have at the moment?

Comment: @PatrickStevens : Learning basic UG maths.

Comment: How basic? What have you already covered? Do you know any number theory? Ring theory?

Comment: @PatrickStevens :Not much , that's why I was asking what are the topics that I need to know so as to learn this.